# C - Separating string using other delimiters?

Tags: c, string, scanf, delimiter

I have a string in the format "B1,B3,B4,B6" and would like to assign each number to a variable i.e. num1 = "1", num2 = "3", num3 = "4", and num4 = "6". Is this implementation of sscanf valid?

```
char *num1;
char *num2;
char *num3;
char *num4;
sscanf(str, "B%s,B%s,B%s,B%s", num1, num2, num3, num4);
```

Comment: Why don't you try it out yourself first, and *then* post a question regarding any problems you may encounter?

Comment: what output you got after running the above code?

Comment: Short answer: no. And your code is wrong anyway, because `num1` etc. are uninizialized pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that's not really a good way. If you just want the numbers a *numbers*, i.e. as normal `int` values, then use the `"%d"` conversion operator instead, and have your variables be normal `int` variables, which you then pass to `sscanf` using the address-of operator `&`. As in

```
int num1;
int num2;
int num3;
int num4;
sscanf(str, "B%d,B%d,B%d,B%d", &num1, &num2, &num3, &num4);
```

---

If you on the other hand *want* the digits as strings, then use *array* instead of pointers:

```
char num1[2];  // Two characters is enough for a single-character string, plus terminator
char num2[2];
char num3[2];
char num4[2];
sscanf(str, "B%1s,B%1s,B%1s,B%1s", num1, num2, num3, num4);
```

The format `"%1s"` tells `sscanf` to only read a *signle* character.

---

Besides that, you should probably make sure that the `sscanf` call actually parsed the input correctly. This can be done by checking what [`sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) *returns*:

```
if (sscanf(str, "B%d,B%d,B%d,B%d", &num1, &num2, &num3, &num4) == 4)
{
    // All okay
}
else
{
    // Something went wrong
}
```

Comment: Not sure if the OP want this. He he may want this  `char *num1 = "1"` instead of `int num1 = 1`. And the question title also make me believe he wants strings.